# (winui3 with c#)change source data of Xmal UI elements which binded, can not show on this UI element

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

My issue Is:
xaml Element(InfoBar) bind source data from backend, change Message of InfoBar  with Element Property, Source data(which bind Message of InfoBar) changed;

but, when I change source data(witch I bind), InfoBar did not show the message what I changed.

//===================== my idea ========================

I want to create a InfoBar, and you can show info on this InfoBar with method everywhere of this WinUI3 App.

e.g.: InfoBar created on ShellPage, you can show info with method in Page of MainPage.

Framework: .net6.0, IDE: Visual Studio 2022

A WinUI3 Desktop use MVVM, Create with "Template Studio for WinUI" template。

in this template, main techs are:

- using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
- using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

As you know with services.AddSingleton method you can get a single Object， Message of Property bind this data of Object，
then you change this data of Object on everywhere of this App, message of InfoBar  will changed and show new(in theory)。

//============= the procedure of create Element(InfoBar) and bind data========

shellPage.xaml:

```xml
<InfoBar Grid.Row="3" x:Name="ShellTipInfo" Margin="36,5,36,0" x:FieldModifier="Public" 
    IsOpen="{x:Bind ViewModel.TheTipInfoMessage.IsOpen, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"     
    Message="{x:Bind ViewModel.TheTipInfoMessage.Message, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"     
    Severity="Informational"     
    Title="Title"     
    CloseButtonClick="ShellTipInfo_CloseButtonClick" />
```

ShellViewModel.cs

```cs
public class ShellViewModel : ObservableRecipient
{

    public ITipInfoServices TheTipInfoMessage;
    public ShellViewModel(ITipInfoServices _tipInfoMessage )
    {
       TheTipInfoMessage = _tipInfoMessage;
    }

}
```

//============= build service of Object, DependencyInjection ======================

```cs
namespace dnppt.Contracts.Services; 

public interface ITipInfoServices 
{     
    string Message     {         get; set;     }     
    bool IsOpen     {         get; set;     } 
}
```

```cs
namespace dnppt.Services;
public class TipInfoServices : ObservableRecipient, ITipInfoServices
{

    private string message;
    
    public string Message
    {
        get => message;
        set => SetProperty(ref message, value);
    }
    
    
    private bool isOpen = true;
    
    public bool IsOpen
    {
        get => isOpen;
        set => SetProperty(ref isOpen, value);
    }

}
```

register service in App.xaml.cs(DependencyInjection)

```cs
services.AddSingleton<ITipInfoServices, TipInfoServices>();
```

//================== change source data and observe change on InfoBar================
//create Service Object on MainPage，change tipInfoMessage.Message:

MainPage.xaml.cs

```cs
var tipInfoMessage = App.GetService<ITipInfoServices>(); 
tipInfoMessage.IsOpen = true; 
tipInfoMessage.Message = "a message......";
```

The result is, you can not see the message on InfoBar. Why? I confused for a long time...

I read Microsoft document, i haven`t find answer. Could someone can help me?
Very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't bind to an interface, `ITipInfoServices` in this case.

One of these changes should work:

- Use `TipInfoServices` instead of `ITipInfoServices`.

or

- Use cast in xaml:

```xml
IsOpen="{x:Bind ((local:TipInfoServices)ViewModel.TheTipInfoMessage).IsOpen, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"     
Message="{x:Bind ((local:TipInfoServices)ViewModel.TheTipInfoMessage).Message, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Comment: Thank you, Andrew! But I use  `WeakReferenceMessenger` class in  `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Messaging` solve this issue. Use this tech I can send info to this InfoBar with method everywhere of this WinUI3 App.